# Ensuring a valid JavaScript string in security-critical application

Tags: javascript, parsing, validation

I'm writing an application where users can write [custom expressions](https://github.com/m93a/filtrex/) which are then converted to JavaScript functions and executed. The expressions are used for filtering and sorting data from a database and to improve performance I want to be able to run the expressions on my server without worrying about getting hijacked. So the main concern is to ensure that the user cannot do code injection to execute an arbitrary script.

This part of the application makes sure that any string literal present in the user's expression will get converted into a valid JavaScript string literal without any chance of containing malicious code.

In the user's expression, string literal should always match this regex: `/"(?:\\"|\\\\|[^"\\])*"/` (or its equivalent with single-quotes). However since the regex pattern isn't evaluated directly by JavaScript, I don't want to rely on it working exactly as I expect, so I double-check it.

```
function buildString(quote, literal)
{
    quote = String(quote)[0]; // for example `"`
    literal = String(literal); // the user's string literal
    let built = ''; // parsed string

    if (literal[0] !== quote || literal[literal.length-1] !== quote)
        throw new Error(`Unexpected internal error: String literal doesn't begin/end with the right quotation mark.`);

    for (let i = 1; i < literal.length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (literal[i] === "\\")
        {
            i++;
            if (i >= literal.length - 1) throw new Error(`Unexpected internal error: Unescaped backslash at the end of string literal.`);

            if (literal[i] === "\\") built += '\\';
            else if (literal[i] === quote) built += quote;
            else throw new Error(`Unexpected internal error: Invalid escaped character in string literal: ${literal[i]}`);
        }
        else if (literal[i] === quote)
        {
            throw new Error(`Unexpected internal error: String literal contains unescaped quotation mark.`);
        }
        else
        {
            built += literal[i];
        }
    }

    return JSON.stringify(built); // valid JavaScript string literal
}
```

.

Here are some test cases:

```
expect( () => buildString(`'`, `'''`  ) ).throws();
expect( () => buildString(`'`, `'\\'` ) ).throws();
expect( () => buildString(`'`, `'\\"'`) ).throws();
expect( () => buildString(`'`, `'\\n'`) ).throws();

expect( () => buildString(`"`, `"""`  ) ).throws();
expect( () => buildString(`"`, `"\\"` ) ).throws();
expect( () => buildString(`"`, `"\\'"`) ).throws();
expect( () => buildString(`"`, `"\\n"`) ).throws();

// null byte
expect(eval( buildString(`'`, `'\n \\\\ \\' " \u0000'`) )).equals(`\n \\ ' " \u0000`);

// unpaired surrogate
expect(eval( buildString(`"`, `"\uD800"`) )).equals(`\uD800`);
```

Comment: Please add your existing test cases to the question.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the environment of the code you wrote? The combination of "security-critical" and "custom JavaScript code" sounds strange.

Comment: Updated the question to hopefully reflect your comments. @RolandIllig The code written by users is not in JavaScript, but in a [custom expression language](https://github.com/m93a/filtrex). However since it compiles to JavaScript (and quite naively so, instead of abstract syntax tree it emits the source code directly as an string), injection is still an issue.

Comment: Short answer not worthy of an answer-post: `(\042|\047)((?!\1).)*\1` does exactly what you want, matching valid strings, and you can join all inputs and then test this against it. It's exactly the same as `(\'|\")((?!\1).)*\1`, and uses negative-lookaheads and group matching.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix I dimly remember that JavaScript treats U+2028 and U+2029 as line separators. Your secular expression doesn't exclude these characters.

Comment: @RolandIllig On the contrary, Regex is single-line by default.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback! @FreezePhoenix Sadly, single- and double-quoted literals mean different things in the expressions, so I can't use your pattern. But at least I learnt some new regex :) @RolandIllig Matching newlines is not a problem, my regex pattern matches them on purpose and `buildString` deals with that just fine.

Comment: @m93a It didn't, oh well I will remove comment.

Comment: @m93a Alternatively you could just use JSON.parse... also, if it's a JS Function, then you can wrap it in a VM instance, which can have controlled access to variables, and even put on another process which can be terminated if it runs too long - I use this design for arbitrary code evaluation, it's worked so far, nobody has been able to crack it.